# when one thread is stopped(such as OS threading dispatching), how are reorded machine instrctions affected?

Tags: multithreading, assembly

we know CPU can reord instructions. and OS simulate multithreading by dispatch.

following cpu machine instructions:

```
ins0
ins1
ins2
```

thread0 partition these three ins into 2 parts. part0 execute ins0, part1 execute ins1 and ins2. before part0 start, part2 complete. and then thread1 is triggered.

my question is:should part0 be completed before thread1 start? or thread1 start while thread0 complete ins1 and ins2 without completing ins0?

Comment: Short answer is no, but this is a really cryptic question.  Second question is where did you manage to get a single core processor?

Comment: single core processor is just assumption. we can use only one processor on multiprocessors. on multiprocessor, every processor can also simulate multithreading. here I just think about: inside one processor, does thread dispatching produce above case(ins1 and ins2 complete but ins0 not in thread0 when thread1 start)?

Comment: Your question explicitly specifies single core.  If that's not what you want please change it.  What steps are you taking to lock that process to the single core?  Also are instructions machine instructions or lines of code in a higher level language?

Comment: Better title now, good stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that, with very few exceptions, when a CPU switches from one thread to another, it picks an instruction boundary and completes every instruction prior to that boundary and doesn't start any after that boundary. When it resumes, it starts from the first instruction after that boundary.

> To allow the restarting of program or task following the handling of an exception or
>   an interrupt, all exceptions (except aborts) are guaranteed to report exceptions on
>   an instruction boundary. All interrupts are guaranteed to be taken on an instruction
>   boundary.
>   
> ...
>   Interrupts rigorously support restarting of interrupted programs and tasks without
>   loss of continuity. The return instruction pointer saved for an interrupt points to the
>   next instruction to be executed at the instruction boundary where the processor took
>   the interrupt. If the instruction just executed has a repeat prefix, the interrupt is
>   taken at the end of the current iteration with the registers set to execute the next
>   iteration. -- Intel x86 [System Programming Guide](http://www.intel.com/Assets/ja_JP/PDF/manual/253668.pdf), Volume 3A, Part 1, Section 6.6

Comment: I also think it's what you said. any official reference? such as "Intel Software Developer's Manual".thanks.

Comment: Section 6.6 of the [System Programming Guide](http://www.intel.com/Assets/ja_JP/PDF/manual/253668.pdf) Volume 3A, part 1. (Answer modified.)

Comment: ..except, presumably page-faults, where the instruction generating the fault must be run for a second time after the page load.  I don't know how they do that?

Comment: It is explained right in that section: "For fault-class exceptions, the return instruction pointer (saved when the processor
generates an exception) points to the faulting instruction. So, when a program or task is restarted following the handling of a fault, the faulting instruction is restarted (reexecuted)."